# Unable to read values from porperties file in config XML

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, properties, hazelcast

I have placed hazelcast.properties & hazelcast config.xml files, both at classpath. This is my directory structure:

```
resources
|_
| spring-env
| |_
|   dev.properties
|_
  applicationContext-hazelcast.xml
```

Inside my applicationContext-hazelcast.xml:

```
<context:property-placeholder file-encoding="UTF-8" location="classpath:spring-env/dev.properties" /> 
<hz:hazelcast id="instance">
    <hz:config>
        <hz:instance-name>hz_instance</hz:instance-name>
        <hz:group name="dev" password="password"/>
        <hz:network port="${hazelcast.port}" port-auto-increment="false">
            <hz:join>
                <hz:multicast enabled="false"/>
                <hz:tcp-ip enabled="true">
                    <hz:members>${hazelcast.members}</hz:members>
                </hz:tcp-ip>
            </hz:join>              
        </hz:network>
```

Everything works fine, but when the server starts, following appears in logs:

```
INFO: Configuring Hazelcast from 'file:/E:/.../MyApp/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext-hazelcast.xml'.
Sep 16, 2016 3:15:47 PM com.hazelcast.config.AbstractConfigBuilder
WARNING: Could not find a value for property  'hazelcast.port' on node: port
Sep 16, 2016 3:15:47 PM com.hazelcast.config.AbstractConfigBuilder
WARNING: Could not find a value for property  'hazelcast.members' on node: null
```

Although I have these properties specified in my dev.properties file:

```
#hazelcast properties
hazelcast.port = 35701
hazelcast.members = 127.0.0.1
```

Any idea why it is not able to find value for ${hazelcast.port} & ${hazelcast.member} properties from dev.properties file?

NOTE: I'm using same config file for hibernate-second-level cache & for the cache maps which I have configured manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define your properties i.e **hazelcast.port** and **hazelcast.members** in your **system property**, it will work.

Read these properties from your **dev.properties** before the **HazelcastCacheRegionFactory** starts and set into System.property.